# Printscreen automatically reduces resolution

Tags: windows-xp, windows-live-messenger, print-screen

An overseas not-so-tech-savvy friend complains that when she presses PrtScn and pastes the image in MSN Messenger, the transferred image is low-resolution.

I could ask which software she has installed that might be the culprit, but she probably doesn't know, nor does she know how to find out. Perhaps a *HijackThis!* output would be useful, but I want to avoid any difficult steps.

Is there perhaps a setting in MSN Messenger that automatically rescales images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, high res images are automatically scaled down and the compression switched to JPEG. There's no way around it. MS Outlook does this in e-mails as well.

Comment: Does this not happen in the beta version? I have the impression outbound images are not rescaled.